# Where do Hogwarts students get money from while they're at school?

Tags: harry-potter

Do they have to make do with the money they bring from home (when they come to the school in September) or can they work somewhere while they're studying to earn extra cash?

Could it be that they just don't need money at all during their school year?

Comment: Where did you get money from when you were at school?

Comment: At most boarding schools parents can send money in for students to get pocket money (from the school) and they can also post it directly.

Comment: Are you asking about their ability to *earn* 'fresh' money (their access to wealth in general, from parents or work) or their ability to *possess* money they already own (their physical access to individual coins)? If it's the latter then Gringotts could send kids packages of coins securely from their account, I suppose. Generally, kids take what they need out of their accounts during the summer.

Comment: kids take what they need out of their accounts during the summer, and carry it around with them for events like hogsmeade trips but they don't necessarily need to bring money

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Students appear to keep their own money in amongst their personal belongings. The opportunities to spend it are relatively rare until later years.

> *He didn’t have any Muggle money, either. **There was a little wizard
>   gold in the moneybag at the bottom of his trunk,** but the rest of the
>   fortune his parents had left him was stored in a vault at Gringotts
>   Wizarding Bank in London. He’d never be able to drag his trunk all the
>   way to London. Unless …*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - The Knight Bus</sup></sub>

and

> *Harry gave Ron whispered orders and passed him some gold from under
>   the Cloak. They left Zonko’s with their money bags considerably
>   lighter than they had been on entering, but their pockets bulging with
>   Dungbombs, Hiccough Sweets, Frog Spawn Soap and a Nose-Biting Teacup
>   apiece.*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban - Snape’s Grudge</sup></sub>

---

Money can be sent by owl

> *A second, very small parcel contained a note.
>
>   We received your message and enclose your Christmas present. From Uncle Vernon and Aunt Petunia. **Sellotaped to the note was a fifty-pence piece.***
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone - The Mirror of Erise</sup></sub>

---

Apparently they receive pocket money. Also, they can earn extra by taking work from other students.

> **GALLONS OF GALLEONS!**
>
> ***Pocket money failing to keep pace with your outgoings? Like to earn a
>   little extra gold?***
>
> *Contact Fred and George Weasley, Gryffindor common room, for simple,
>   part-time, virtually painless jobs. (We regret that all work is
>   undertaken at applicant’s own risk.)*
>
> <sup><sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix - Professor Umbridge</sub></sup>

Answer (score 24):

Their parents pay for stuff, as we see the Weasleys paying for Ron/Ginny's stuff. Hogwarts also has a fund for students who can't pay for stuff, as Dumbledore tells Tom Riddle:

> When he had finished, he turned to Dumbledore and said baldly, "I haven't got any money."
>   "That is easily remedied," said Dumbledore, drawing a leather money-pouch from his pocket. "There is a fund at Hogwarts for those who require assistance to buy books and robes. You might have to buy some of your spellbooks and so on secondhand, but -"
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, chapter 13</sub>

Also, (thanks @Gallifeyan!) apparently the Ministry pays for all magical tuition:

> @emmalineonline1 There's no tuition fee! The Ministry of Magic covers the cost of all magical education!
>   <sub>JKR on [twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/622118373061709824)</sub>

Comment: You might want to add that tweet by JKR that Ministry pays for tuition of all students. [Here, for instance](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/25153/where-did-hogwarts-get-money-for-salaries-food-and-other-purchases?rq=1)

Comment: This money seems to cover the purchase of items needed for their schooling, not out-of-pocket expenses.

Comment: @Valorum - yes, that's what I assumed the question was asking about.

Comment: The question is asking about how they get money after their arrival, not before - "*Do they have to do with the money they bring from home when they come to the school in September?*"

Comment: I've edited the question to make it a little clearer